# Making any changes on this page may cause breaking authentication methods for all your Team members

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

How does Stack Overflow allow login via non-[SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) ([SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider_(SAML))) authentication? If the [IdP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider) is down? Is there a failover "back door" login page/URL for the administrator to login and disable SSO? On the *Settings* page it says:

***"Making any changes on this page may cause breaking authentication methods for all your Team members and revoke their access. If you'd like help making changes, contact Customer Support."***

[Admin settings => Authentication => Single sign-on (SSO)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH4rR.png)

Answer (score 5):

We do not provide any kind of backdoor like this as it could open security holes where a non-work email address attached to the account becomes compromised and allows access to the team despite the team's security settings. We would not want such a compromised account to be able to access the team without re-verifying their access via the IdP, particularly an account which was a team admin.

If your IdP is down and you would prefer to disable SSO completely while it is offline, a team admin will need to [contact us](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26) directly and request that SSO be turned off for the team. We wouldn't recommend doing this unless you plan on the IdP being down for a considerable amount of time. As the message on the page indicates, this can break authentication for your entire team if they have only ever used SSO for login on Stack Overflow - they would need to utilize account recovery in order to regain access to their accounts and ensure they use the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

- Most of the times, the IdP that provides authentication to the user through SSO is mostly available according to their specified and published [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement). In case, if the IdP is not available for authentication, the administrator user can still log in to Stack Overflow by resetting the password through different methods of multi-factor authentication provided during setting up of the SSO SAML sign in options.
- When you use the forgot password option, the Stack Overflow [SSPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-service_password_reset) functionality will send a password reset link on the mail id that was set for login purposes as well as after resetting the password for administrator user on Stack Overflow teams, the second option set while configuring the [MFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication), i.e., phone number, device authenticator app, etc. will receive a confirmation prompt to authorize the password reset on the Stack Overflow platform itself. Thus, once the identity is confirmed for the administrator user, he/she can then configure other options available for authentication to Stack Overflow teams.
- And in case, the IdP is unable to give you login access to your mail platform due to outage issues, you can freely contact their support team to facilitate access to your account in Stack Overflow teams. The support team contact is available on their website in the *Contact Us* section.

Please find the below link for more understanding:

*[Handling failure of SAML IdP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629341/handling-failure-of-saml-idp)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kartik!
In my case, I have an on-premise ADFS SSO, that I have many SPs use it as an IdP for authentication. Such as AWS, Azure, Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, Jenkins JAMF etc. and they all have an option for a local admin login that bypasses the SAML SSO. That's why I was wondering if they had a backdoor admin login in case the identity provider is not available.